# Record Audio in Ableton Live from Behringer Digital Pro Mixer DDM4000

Tags: recording, ableton-live, homerecording, mixer, turntables

I connect OUT B from Behringer Digital Pro Mixer DDM4000 to Scarlett 2i/4,
on Ableton -> Preferences -> Audio Input Device -> Scarlett 2i4 USB.
on Audio Track I select Audio From Ext. In, but no signal arrive on 1/2, 1 or 2 (??)

Comment: I don't own/know the parts - therefore just general things I would check: is there some bundled software - either with the Behringer or the Focusrite - which can show you if there's any signal arriving at your computer? Did it work before and if, what did you change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what, idk if the 2i4 is the right Audio Interface. I just purchased the DDM4000 yesterday and the sales person was telling me that you need at minimum the 4i4. I have the Native Instruments DJ 8 Audio Interface so I'll try to use that one, but want to connect it to Ableton as well, though really just wanted to plainly mix out of Traktor...